# SQL update from same table based on similarity in another table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`. `t1` has these columns: `id, name, cost`. `t2` has `id, col1, col2, typeid`.

`id`s are unique in `t2`.

The two are linked through `id`. `typeid` is either 1 or 2.

I want to update the cost of Type 2 (`typeid=2`) products like this:

For every Type 2 product in `t1` check if there is a Type 1 product that has the same `col1` and `col2` in `t2`, and if there is, assign the Type 1 product's cost to to the Type 2's. If there aren't any similar Type 1s then do nothing.

The python pseudocode would be this:

```
for row in t1:
    if t2[row.id].typeid==2:
        actualcol1=t2[row.id].col1
        actualcol2=t2[row.id].col2
        
        for rows in t2:
            if rows.typeid==1 and rows.col1=actualcol1 and rows.col2=actualcol2:
                actid=id
                row.cost=t1[actid].cost
                break
```

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVck8.png)

How would I do this as an SQL update?

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: Please consider aadding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help.

Comment: I'd advise looking at a question that features both UPDATE and JOIN clauses. They're one of the most common SQL Server questions

Comment: What does the python have to do with the SQL here?

Comment: What have you tried in T-SQL?